# Qlikview OLEDB Connection string missing out values when ODBC works fine with the same extract file

Tags: odbc, oledb, qlikview, oledbconnection

OLEDB Connection string missing out values when ODBC works fine with the same extract file.

I have a simple extract file with 1 query:

```
QUALIFY *;

MyQVTable:
LOAD *;

SELECT * FROM MyTable;

STORE MyQVTable INTO $(vQVDDirectory)\MyQVTable.qvd;

DROP table MyQVTable;
```

If I use the OLEDB connection string:

```
OLEDB CONNECT TO [Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Data Source=SERVER;Extended Properties=""] (XPassword is PASSWORD);
```

It doesn’t return ALL my data but it does if I use ODBC

```
ODBC CONNECT TO [SERVER;DBQ=SERVER] (XUserId is USERNAME, XPassword is PASSWORD);
```